# for each loop in javascript with json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have the following code, which is a restful json api.

```
//  Program guide Rest

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
      url: "http://engridmedia.com/next/api/epg/scheduler/id/200",
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        alert("EPG Success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('EPG Failed!');
    },
})

.then(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        var prefix = (i == 0 ? "" : i.toString());

        $('.programtitle' + prefix).append(data[i].program_title);
        $('.ch-start' + prefix).append(data[i].start_time);
        $('.ch-end' + prefix).append(data[i].end_time);
        $('.ch-programdesc' + prefix).append(data[i].desc);


    }
});
```

I want to use the data in my phonegap html . that means i would have to call each data by doing this   a bunch of times since i will have over 20 data in the array  and sometimes less. is there a for each loop in javascript to do this easily like echoing data from the database in php?

```
 <?php foreach ($query as $row)
{ ;?>
  <h3><?php echo $row -> program_title; ?> | <?php echo $row -> start_time; ?> | <?php echo $row -> end_time; ?></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
   <?php echo $row -> desc; ?>
    </p>
  </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Look at "for in" loop - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ja408 sayed you should use this syntax in javascript :

```
for(var k in yourJson) {
   console.log(k, result[k]);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: but why do i have to use console log . i thought that only print values in the console of the browser? sorry am not too familiar with javascript. i thought document was the way to print it inside the page?

Comment: you dont need the console.log you shold remove it becase old ie dont support this function.